# Mysql missing data inserted with goroutines

Tags: mysql, go, goroutine, go-gorm

I'm updating records from another resource into the database.

```
// Turn into batches with batchSize == 10
    batches := service.TurnIntoBatches(cModels, 10)

// Sync to our db
var wg sync.WaitGroup
customerChannel := make(chan []*model.Customer, len(batches))

for _, batch := range batches {
    wg.Add(1)
    go UpdateCustomers(batch, &wg, uc.customerRp, customerChannel)
}
wg.Wait()
close(customerChannel)


func UpdateCustomers(customers []*model.Customer,
    wg *sync.WaitGroup,
    rp repository.CustomerRepositoryInterface,
    channel chan []*model.Customer) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for _, c := range customers {
        //err := Update logic
        if err != nil {
            logger.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
                "error":                err,
            }).WithError(err).Error("Updating failed!")
        }
    }
}
```

If I got 50 records, that's 5 batches of 10. 
There are 50 `insert query`, as expected. All of them returned `[1 rows affected or returned ]`

However, if I query from the database, there are sometimes 45 or 46 records.
What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you change the batch size from 10 to 50?

Comment: It works as expected. All 50 records are inserted/updated @Mark
Can this be a problem relating to db configuration?

Comment: Your code says Update but you say insert, which is it? Are you showing us the correct code? Is the code in the question executing INSERT or UPDATE queries?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I check if the record exist -> Update. If not -> Create

Comment: What is the purpose of `customerChannel` here? You send to it five times and receive from it once, discarding the value.

Comment: Looks like 1 customer is dropped per batch. Or one customer is duplicated per batch. Suggest printing size of customers in UpdateCustomers before range. Print each unique customer before insert inside range. Are they all as intended?

Comment: @Adrian yes that was intended to use the data using the channel. Thanks for pointing out that I was just discarding it once

Comment: @Mark There was 50 records, I checked with debug mode. Interestingly enough, if I hit the request twice, all 50 records will be inserted. Gorm printed that insert statement returns some rows that does not exist inside the database.

Comment: @TrầnXuânHuy I think there's more going on than we can see in the code you posted. How many databases do you have? If you have one db, running inserts in parallel probably won't help much, because the inserts compete for a single resource. If possible, use a simple loop over `cModels`, inserting one by one.

Comment: @Mark There's only 1 database. I am currently making prepared statements for batches and it works. However, I think that using many goroutines is another way to speed up inserting process? `running inserts in parallel probably won't help much, because the inserts compete for a single resource`, I think I need more readings about this. Can you give me some reference? Thanks

Comment: @TrầnXuânHuy goroutines might speed it up, but not necessarily, and it's more complex. Ideally, you can measure and compare. For reference, I suggest [Rob Pike's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso) is worth watching. Alternatively, you may be able to use [mysql batch load](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).